# Laravel Validate Failed and automatically redirect to login page

Tags: php, laravel

I use laravel 9, inertia and vue js on my production mode project. I have deploy my project to shared hosting.

But if i test to fill blank the form input, the validation is not working, and redirect me back to login page. My expecation is the validate message will show under the textbox, but its not.

My store function:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|unique:kecamatans',
        'order' => 'required',
    ]);

    Kecamatan::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'order' => $request->order,
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('apps.kecamatans.index');
}
```

My form:

```
<form @submit.prevent="submit">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="fw-bold">Nama Kecamatan</label>
        <input class="form-control" v-model="form.name" :class="{ 'is-invalid': errors.name }" type="text"
            placeholder="Nama kecamatan">
    </div>
    <div v-if="errors.name" class="alert alert-danger">
        {{ errors.name }}
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="fw-bold">Urutan</label>
        <input class="form-control" v-model="form.order" :class="{ 'is-invalid': errors.order }" type="text"
            placeholder="Urutan">
    </div>
    <div v-if="errors.order" class="alert alert-danger">
        {{ errors.order }}
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <ButtonInCreateVue url="kecamatans"></ButtonInCreateVue>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My setup script:

```
setup() {
        const form = reactive({
            name: '',
            order: '',
            latitude: '',
            longitude: ''
        });

        const submit = () => {
            Inertia.post('/apps/kecamatans', {
                name: form.name,
                order: form.order,
            }, {
                onSuccess: () => {
                    successAlert('Kecamatan', 'ditambah')
                },
            });
        }

        return {
            form,
            submit,
        }
    }
```

My route:

```
Route::resource('/kecamatans', \App\Http\Controllers\Apps\KecamatanController::class, ['as' => 'apps'])
            ->middleware('permission:kecamatans.index|kecamatans.create|kecamatans.edit|kecamatans.delete');
```

Its working normally on my local computer, but not working on hosting. And if i check console log, there is no error.

Comment: Have you updated ```APP_URL``` in your .env file w.r.t your domain ?

Comment: yes im, but if i add ```protected $except = [ '*' ];``` in verifyCsrfToken Middleware, its will work normally

Comment: where is this `route` reside in? does the `Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession` enabled for the route? anyway, see on browser console's network tab and see what your actual error is.

Comment: your problem is similar with [this one](https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia-laravel/issues/356).

Comment: @BagusTesa i have try that, still not work, but not redirect me to login page

Answer (score 0):

Have you passed your authentication token in ajax request?
Try passing authonetication token in your headers, then it should work.